# How to launch instrument tool in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

How do I launch instrument tool in Xcode environment for testing the memory leaks?
Note: I'm not connected with the device, checking it only with the simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu, under run, "Run with performance tool", then select your favorite performance tool.

Answer (score 3):

To launch Instruments from the Xcode menu

1. Open Xcode.
2. Choose Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Instruments.

[image: INSTRUMENTS MENU ITEM IN XCODE]